# Sent disabled/readonly select tag data on form submission

Tags: jquery, html

How to sent disabled select tag on form submission with out using hidden tag and disabling & re-enabling just before form submit.

Comment: erm.......... huh!?

Comment: Is it disabled when you submit the form, but you still want the data POSTed? In that case, I'd just enable it quickly on 'submit'.

Answer (score 0):

I did with `$('#idname').css('pointer-events','none');` but on tab is getting focus on select to change.
Change of select tag value should not happen.